# How to make an radar that takes variables from mqtt

Tags: html, css

So I want to make a radar like a sonar. So I will get a variable from an MQTT subscription. So on this radar, if it outputs 180 degrees and 50 on the distance I want it to be there on the radar. Also when the sweep has registered 180 degrees and 50 on the distance I want for example a red dot to pop up and then when the sweep passed it will fade away and then maybe pop up somewhere else if the variable has changed. How will I be able to do this and what language do I need to use. Like this one but I want the red dots on it that is controlled by MQTT variables. This is the code for the radar and the sweep.

```css
 html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  --green: rgb(40, 133, 40);
  --size: 500px;
}

body {
  background: #232;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.status {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial,
    sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 9px 7px 32px;
  color: #777;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%;
  left: -5%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.status::before,
.status::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #181818;
}

.status::after {
  background: radial-gradient(var(--green) 60%, darkgreen 40%);
  animation: light 1.2s infinite alternate
    cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px var(--green);
}

@keyframes light {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -10%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #222, #333);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 2px #111;
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes scan {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.circle-huge {
  width: calc(var(--size) * 0.9);
  height: calc(var(--size) * 0.9);
  border: 4px solid var(--green);
  --gradient: black 0%, black 12.35%, var(--green) 12.35%, var(--green) 12.55%,
    black 12.56%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(var(--gradient)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--gradient)),
    radial-gradient(black 33%, var(--green));
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 4px #222, 0 3px 0 5px #343;
}

.circle-huge::before {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--green) 50%, black 50%),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, var(--green) 50%);
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  will-change: opacity;
  animation: scan 5s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.circle-big {
  --this-size: calc(var(--size) * 0.7);
  width: var(--this-size);
  height: var(--this-size);
}

.circle-medium {
  --this-size: calc(var(--size) * 0.5);
  width: var(--this-size);
  height: var(--this-size);
}

.circle-small {
  --this-size: calc(var(--size) * 0.3);
  width: var(--this-size);
  height: var(--this-size);
}

.circle-tiny {
  --this-size: calc(var(--size) * 0.15);
  width: var(--this-size);
  height: var(--this-size);
}

.circle-center {
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  border-color: firebrick;
  background: firebrick;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: -16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #111;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-first {
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px 5px 1px;
}

.logo-second {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.screw {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: -35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #222;
}

.screw:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(35deg);
  background: #333;
}

.screw:nth-of-type(even):after {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(105deg);
}

.screw:nth-of-type(n + 4):after {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(80deg);
}

.screw-1 {
  left: initial;
  right: -35px;
}

.screw-2 {
  top: initial;
  left: -35px;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.screw-3 {
  left: initial;
  top: initial;
  right: -35px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Military Radar System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="screw"></div>
  <div class="screw screw-1"></div>
  <div class="screw screw-2"></div>
  <div class="screw screw-3"></div>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-first">RADAR</div>
    <div class="logo-second">SYSTEM</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle circle-huge">
    <div class="circle circle-big">
      <div class="circle circle-medium">
        <div class="circle circle-small">
          <div class="circle circle-tiny">
            <div class="circle circle-center"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">SCANNING</div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```